# Jenkins do not run Protractor Tests

Tags: node.js, jenkins, protractor

I am new in Jenkins. I want run automatically my Protractor tests in Jenkins job.
And Jenkins can not  automatically find webdriver-manager to update.
This is my protractor.confing.js:

```
const { SpecReporter } = require('jasmine-spec-reporter');

exports.config = {
  allScriptsTimeout: 11000,
  specs: [
    './e2e/**/*.e2e-spec.ts'
  ],
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
  },
  directConnect: true,
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4200/',
  framework: 'jasmine',
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000,
    print: function () { }
  },
  suites: {
    full:'e2e/**/**/*.ts',
   // smoke: 'e2e/tests/home/home.page-spec.ts ',
  },

  onPrepare() {
    var Jasmine2HtmlReporter = require('protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter');

    require('ts-node').register({
     // project: 'e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json',
    });
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({ spec: { displayStacktrace: true } }));
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new Jasmine2HtmlReporter({
      savePath: './e2e/report',
      screenshotsFolder: 'images'
    }));

  }
};
```

This is my package.js file:

```
{
    "name": "ui",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "license": "MIT",
    "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start": "ng serve",
        "build": "ng build --prod",
        "test": "ng test",
        "lint": "ng lint",
        "e2e": "ng e2e"
    },
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "5.2.0",
        "@angular/common": "5.2.0",
        "@angular/compiler": "5.2.0",
        "@angular/core": "5.2.0",
        "@angular/forms": "5.2.0",
        "@angular/http": "5.2.11",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.0",
        "@angular/router": "5.2.0",
        "bootstrap": "4.1.1",
        "core-js": "2.4.1",
        "jquery": "3.3.1",
        "ngx-bootstrap": "^3.0.1",
        "popper.js": "^1.14.3",
        "protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter": "0.0.7",
        "protractor-jasmine2-reporter": "^1.1.0",
        "protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter": "^0.5.0",
        "rxjs": "5.5.6",
        "zone.js": "0.8.19"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@angular/cli": "1.7.3",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.0",
        "@angular/language-service": "5.2.0",
        "@types/jasmine": "2.8.3",
        "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.2",
        "@types/node": "6.0.60",
        "codelyzer": "4.0.1",
        "jasmine-core": "2.8.0",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.2.1",
        "karma": "2.0.2",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "1.2.1",
        "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "0.2.2",
        "protractor": "5.3.2",
        "ts-node": "4.1.0",
        "tslint": "5.9.1",
        "typescript": "2.5.3"
    }
}
```

In my Jenkins job I pull code from BitBucket repository. And I execute Windows batch commands:

- cd NewGenProject/ui/
- npm install
- npm -g install protractor
- npm install -g @angular/cli
- npm i jasmine-spec-reporter
- ng e2e

And i have error in console :

```
Started by user Admin
Building in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\newGen_protractor
 > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe config remote.origin.url https://___somi@bitbucket.org/night_riders/desingstudio_new_gen.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://___somi@bitbucket.org/night_riders/desingstudio_new_gen.git
 > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe --version # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials 
 > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe fetch --tags --progress https://___somi@bitbucket.org/night_riders/desingstudio_new_gen.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
Seen branch in repository origin/application.properties
Seen branch in repository origin/develop
Seen branch in repository origin/features/conf_view_changes
Seen branch in repository origin/master
Seen 4 remote branches
 > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe show-ref --tags -d # timeout=10
Checking out Revision 7be6f493b7de7a1d78fdc66db21a85f58db4f50b (origin/application.properties)
 > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe checkout -f 7be6f493b7de7a1d78fdc66db21a85f58db4f50b
Commit message: "protractor"
 > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe rev-list --no-walk 7be6f493b7de7a1d78fdc66db21a85f58db4f50b # timeout=10
[newGen_protractor] $ cmd /c call C:\Windows\TEMP\jenkins1838595441649612146.bat

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\newGen_protractor>cd NewGenProject/ui/ 

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\newGen_protractor\NewGenProject\ui>npm install 
npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.4.8: Use uuid module instead
npm WARN deprecated tough-cookie@2.2.2: ReDoS vulnerability parsing Set-Cookie https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/130
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.3.0: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN @angular/http@5.2.11 requires a peer of @angular/core@5.2.11 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/http@5.2.11 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser@5.2.11 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ngx-bootstrap@3.0.1 requires a peer of @angular/common@>=6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ngx-bootstrap@3.0.1 requires a peer of @angular/core@>=6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN The package protractor is included as both a dev and production dependency.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

audited 7457 packages in 66.478s
found 20 vulnerabilities (2 low, 12 moderate, 6 high)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
[newGen_protractor] $ cmd /c call C:\Windows\TEMP\jenkins2673585650827143440.bat

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\newGen_protractor>cd NewGenProject/ui/ 

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\newGen_protractor\NewGenProject\ui>npm -g install protractor 
C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\npm\protractor -> C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\bin\protractor
C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\npm\webdriver-manager -> C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\bin\webdriver-manager
+ protractor@5.4.1
updated 1 package in 18.687s
[newGen_protractor] $ cmd /c call C:\Windows\TEMP\jenkins3055133064298792255.bat

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\newGen_protractor>cd NewGenProject/ui/ 

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\newGen_protractor\NewGenProject\ui>npm install -g @angular/cli 
C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng -> C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

+ @angular/cli@6.2.2
updated 6 packages in 61.913s
[newGen_protractor] $ cmd /c call C:\Windows\TEMP\jenkins3326917024779106456.bat

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\newGen_protractor>cd NewGenProject/ui/ 

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\newGen_protractor\NewGenProject\ui>npm i jasmine-spec-reporter 
npm WARN @angular/http@5.2.11 requires a peer of @angular/core@5.2.11 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/http@5.2.11 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser@5.2.11 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ngx-bootstrap@3.0.1 requires a peer of @angular/common@>=6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ngx-bootstrap@3.0.1 requires a peer of @angular/core@>=6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN The package protractor is included as both a dev and production dependency.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

+ jasmine-spec-reporter@4.2.1
updated 1 package and audited 7457 packages in 37.074s
found 20 vulnerabilities (2 low, 12 moderate, 6 high)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
[newGen_protractor] $ cmd /c call C:\Windows\TEMP\jenkins1987663965716966083.bat

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\newGen_protractor>cd NewGenProject/ui/ 

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\newGen_protractor\NewGenProject\ui>ng e2e  
Your global Angular CLI version (6.2.1) is greater than your local
version (1.7.3). The local Angular CLI version is used.

To disable this warning use "ng config -g cli.warnings.versionMismatch false".
** NG Live Development Server is listening on localhost:49156, open your browser on http://localhost:49156/ **
[0mDate: [1m[37m2018-09-16T13:31:53.250Z[39m[22m[0m
[0mHash: [1m[37mb824d4ffc831966e2310[39m[22m[0m
[0mTime: [1m[37m46284[39m[22mms[0m
[0mchunk {[1m[33minline[39m[22m} [1m[32minline.bundle.js, inline.bundle.js.map[39m[22m (inline) 3.89 kB [1m[33m[entry][39m[22m[1m[32m [rendered][39m[22m[0m
[0mchunk {[1m[33mmain[39m[22m} [1m[32mmain.bundle.js, main.bundle.js.map[39m[22m (main) 240 kB [1m[33m[initial][39m[22m[1m[32m [rendered][39m[22m[0m
[0mchunk {[1m[33mpolyfills[39m[22m} [1m[32mpolyfills.bundle.js, polyfills.bundle.js.map[39m[22m (polyfills) 203 kB [1m[33m[initial][39m[22m[1m[32m [rendered][39m[22m[0m
[0mchunk {[1m[33mscripts[39m[22m} [1m[32mscripts.bundle.js, scripts.bundle.js.map[39m[22m (scripts) 158 kB [1m[33m[initial][39m[22m[1m[32m [rendered][39m[22m[0m
[0mchunk {[1m[33mstyles[39m[22m} [1m[32mstyles.bundle.js, styles.bundle.js.map[39m[22m (styles) 158 kB [1m[33m[initial][39m[22m[1m[32m [rendered][39m[22m[0m
[0mchunk {[1m[33mvendor[39m[22m} [1m[32mvendor.bundle.js, vendor.bundle.js.map[39m[22m (vendor) 6.04 MB [1m[33m[initial][39m[22m[1m[32m [rendered][39m[22m[0m
(node:2336) [DEP0022] DeprecationWarning: os.tmpDir() is deprecated. Use os.tmpdir() instead.
Cannot automatically find webdriver-manager to update.
Update webdriver-manager manually and run 'ng e2e --no-webdriver-update' instead.
Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Is a selenium server or webdriver-manager running on your Jenkins server?

Comment: I did not run the selenium server. How to do it?

Comment: I using windows server 2012.